# Double category : what are the names of the two kind of morphisms?

Tags: category-theory

There are two conventions for what horizontal and vertical morphisms are.

Instead of referring to refer to their direction, what are there existing non-ambiguous terminologies for the two kind of morphisms ?

Throwing a few pairs of the kind of thing I am asking if its not clear :

- pro-morphisms VS non-pro-morphisms (from 'profunctor')
- dist-morphisms VS fun-morphisms (from 'distributor' )
- rel-morphisms VS map-morphisms (from 'relators' - and 'maps' from arrow with a right adjoint)

Comment: I've heard "tight" and "loose", and less formally I've heard people use "the strong direction" and "the weak direction".

Comment: thank you. it's definitely better than vertical and horizontal !

Comment: (The usual) double categories are symmetric though, so why would you want to give the morphisms asymmetric names?

Comment: @jgon I meant weak double categories, obviously, for which vertical and horizontal is a poor terminology